# C (UNIX Environment) Fork system call never returning 0, not creating child process

Tags: c, unix, fork

Can someone explain why my calls to fork below are not doing anything?  They are never equal to zero, or negative, they are only positive.  So I never get to go into/create any child processes.

I can't create a child B, C, or D since the fork calls don't do anything.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

//Creates Three Processes B,C,D which communicate data through pipes.
int main() {
  int     fd[2], nbytes;
  pid_t   childpidB, childpidC, childpidD;
  pipe(fd);
  if((childpidB = fork()) < 0)
    {
      perror("fork B error.\n");
      exit(1);
    }
  if(childpidB == 0) //
    {
      close(fd[0]);
      char writeparam[100];
      sprintf(writeparam, "%d", fd[0]);
      char *arg[3];
      arg[0] = "PipeW1";
      arg[1] = writeparam[100];
      arg[2] = NULL;
      execv("PipeW1",arg);
      close(fd[1]);
    }
  if((childpidC = fork()) < 0)
    {
      perror("fork C error.\n");
      exit(1);
    }
  if(childpidC == 0) 
    {
      close(fd[0]);
      char writeparam[100];
      sprintf(writeparam, "%d", fd[0]);
      char *arg[3];
      arg[0] = "PipeW2";
      arg[1] = writeparam[100];
      arg[2] = NULL;
      execv("PipeW2",arg);
      close(fd[1]);
    }
  if((childpidD = fork()) < 0)
    {
      perror("fork D error\n");
      exit(1);
    }
  if(childpidD == 0) 
    {
      close(fd[1]);
      char readparam[100];
      sprintf(readparam, "%d", fd[1]);
      char *arg[3];
      arg[0] = "PipeR";
      arg[1] = readparam[100];
      arg[2] = NULL;
      execv("PipeR",arg);
      close(fd[0]);
    }
  return 0;
}
```

This is really killing me because it just makes no sense.  Could it be something wrong with my debugger?  To add more detail, I have tried adding printf("GOT HERE"); statements after each if xxx == 0, and nothing gets printed out ever.

Sorry for not adding much more detail, I don't know what more to say.  It's really perplexing to be honest.  The forks just aren't working the way they... normally should?

Comment: What about adding `printf("GOT HERE\n");`?

Comment: Have you tried adding some logic to check that the fork was successful? e.g., `if (childpidX > 0)`

Comment: Yes when I tried a greater than xxx it did go into that.

Comment: But if you `printf()` something inside `if(childpidC == 0)` block, for example, yoy get it printed.

Comment: I tried the printf("GOT HERE\n"); to flush out and it did print that out.  But, it's still not running anything in the process like it should.

Comment: `arg[1] = readparam[10];`, `arg[1] = writeparam[100];` etc are clearly wrong, your compiler should be shouting this at you.

Comment: Sigh, it's not, I have no idea whats going on but my debugger must be screwed.  But thanks for catching that, yea that was blatant.

Comment: How do you know it's "not running anything"? The only thing potentially visible in there is the `execv()` calls, and you never check to see if they succeeded. Which they might not be, since `execv()` requires a path, and you're not providing a fully qualified one, so it might not be finding the executables. And your arguments were wrong, as I already mentioned.

Comment: That means you are asking the wrong question, `fork` works, the problem is probably in the call to `execv`.

Comment: The next call after execv should always be _exit(127). I don't know what you think those close fd calls are supposed to accomplish.

Comment: @Random832: I agree that there should be an exit after the `execv()`; in my view, the child that failed to `execv()` should normally also report the error message on standard error.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths: there's a 'path' specified; it is the file in the current directory.  I agree that the `execv()` commands are not properly handled with an error message and exit after the `execv()` returns.  There's no need to check the return value from `execv()` and friends; if they return, they failed.

Comment: Can you trust the state of the stdio streams after a fork? Might be better to use write()

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: "you're not providing a fully qualified one", rather than not providing one at all. Something along the lines of `execv("grep", ...)` is not an uncommon error, for instance.

Comment: @Random832: yes, you can trust the state of the streams.  It is a good idea to use `fflush(0)` _before_ the `fork()` so there's no pending standard output, for example.  It is fine to write to `stderr`; it is typically less sensible to write to `stdout`.  I said 'standard error' which covers file descriptor 2 as well as `stderr`, but that's a subtle detail.  I use `fprintf(stderr, "failed to exec %s\n", arg[0]);` or its equivalent, sometimes with the system error (from `errno` and `strerror()`) to report the error.

Comment: @Random832: note that if there is pending output in standard output buffer (in particular), then the output may appear twice if both the parent and the child end up flushing standard output after the `fork()`.  That's why the `fflush(0)` before the `fork()` is a good idea. It is also why the standard recommendation is to use `_exit()` instead of `exit()`; that avoids executing `atexit()` handlers and flushing standard I/O channels (meaning not only standard input, output, error, but also any other file stream).

Answer (score 1):

Adding printfs after the fork calls to print the resulting pids:

```
 ./fk 
 childpidB = 3311
 childpidB = 0
 childpidC = 3312
 childpidC = 0
 childpidD = 3313
 childpidD = 3314
 childpidC = 3316
 childpidD = 3317
 childpidD = 0
 childpidD = 0
 childpidD = 0
 childpidC = 0
 childpidD = 331a
 childpidD = 0
```

So, the pids are not only equal to zero, additional forks are being done by the children because the execv() calls are broken. Your debugger doesn't seem to be tracking children processes. If you're using gdb see:

https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Forks.html#Forks